# Spring MVC: jackson-mapper-asl not work with Spring 4

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

I am trying to convert List of objects into json with the help of `jackson-mapper-asl` libraries, but in response i got http `406` error. `jackson-mapper-asl` libraries are on my class path. Following is my Spring MVC controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/find-sub-categories/{parentId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public List<ProductCategory> findSubCategories(@PathVariable(value="parentId") ProductCategory productCategory) {
    logger.info("In ADMIN findSubCategories Contoller AJAX GET");

    List<ProductCategory> categories = productCategoryService.findAllChildProductCategoriesByParent(productCategory);
    return categories;
}
```

My Ajax request code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url+"/"+parentId,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                var arr = $.parseJSON(result);
-----------------------
```

Comment: you are using the wrong jackson dependencies check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825276/spring-4-restcontroller-json-characteristics-not-acceptable-according-to-the-re

Comment: are you adding ?contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",  dataType : "json", also what version of jackson using? support for Jackson has been focused on 2.0+ in spring 4

Answer (score 12):

With `spring 4`, we need to use following dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The `jackson-mapper-asl` is used with `spring 3.x`. Thanks to @Master Slave for valid comment. Click here for more information:  [Spring 4 RestController JSON: characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825276/spring-4-restcontroller-json-characteristics-not-acceptable-according-to-the-re)

Comment: If I add the above dependency, my tomcat server 8 is getting stopped. What will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you used in valid path variable param type  ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/find-sub-categories/{parentId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public List<ProductCategory>   findSubCategories@PathVariable(value="parentId") ProductCategory productCategory)
```

instead of it, use the following method header it may work

```
 @ResponseBody public List<ProductCategory>   findSubCategories(@PathVariable Integer parentId)
```

Comment: the way i use `@PathVariable` is Spring-Data functionality. The Problem only with the wrong dependency that i used. I post the answer already.