# spring 4 mvc app - application level exception handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am moving my spring web app from Spring 3.2 to 4.1.

In 3.2, the following exception handler works very well for catching exceptions from the entire applicaton.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionProcessor {
    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(AppException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorInfo handleAppException(AppException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ErrorInfo ret = new ErrorInfo(ex.getMessage(), new Date(), ex.getExtras());
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(ex.getCode().getStatusCode());

        return ret;
    }
}
```

However when I move to 4.1, I get the following exception stack trace:

```
ERROR Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public com.momoe.handler.RestExceptionProcessor$ErrorInfo com.momoe.handler.RestExceptionProcessor.handleAppException(com.momoe.commons.AppException,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:167) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE].....
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you expect to return JSON as a response? Is Jackson on your classpath (for content negotiation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading from spring 3.x to 4.1 you need to change from jackson 1.9.x to jackson 2.x. In jackson 2.x the package structure got migrated from org.codehaus to `com.fasterxml`.

If you don't have com.fasterxml jackson on your classpath the result will be the same as if you're missing the jackson altogether, outputting the *Could not find acceptable representation* message in logs. If you're using maven it should be enough to include *jackson-databind*, it will transitively include *jackson-annotation* and *jackson-core*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

a bit more details available here
[Spring 4 RestController JSON: characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825276/spring-4-restcontroller-json-characteristics-not-acceptable-according-to-the-re/26826136#26826136)

Comment: What was confusing was there are 2.x versions available for both codehaus and fasterxml. I was using the codehaus 2.x version.