# 406 Not Acceptable in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a web app in spring MVC.

I want to retrieve List of patient (collection) using Ajax. But it throws me error of 406 not acceptable

**Jsp File**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'searchPatient',
                        //data: "uhid=" + $("#uhid").val() + "&type=" + $("#type").val(),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

**
**Controller File**

```
@RequestMapping("/searchPatient")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getPatient() 
    {
             List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("hello");
        return s;
    }
```

[image: Console View]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825276/spring-4-restcontroller-json-characteristics-not-acceptable-according-to-the-re/26826136#26826136) helps

Comment: try removing `contentType` since you are not sending any data to server and for this server rejects the request. Also GET request should not have a request body. It will be rejected by most application server. refer for [406 HTTP status](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html)

Comment: I have changed it to Post request but still not working

Answer (score 0):

your request URI is http://…/HMIS/searchPatient, so make sure your DispatcherServlet is mapped to /HMIS/* or it's existed in your controller  @RequestMapping

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I also had this error an solved it adding the definition for MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter like this:

```
<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<!-- Bind the return value of the Rest service to the ResponseBody. -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />          
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

[Link to the original answer](https://coderanch.com/t/650827/frameworks/acceptable-message-AJAX-call-Spring) hope it helps someone else.